# Flutter: firebase_admob ads are not showing

Tags: admob, flutter

I believe I follow the steps exactly:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_admob

...but nothing. No real ads, no test ads, nothing in "flutter run", nothing in "flutter build". I tried InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId and FirebaseAdMob.testAppId and testDevices ...

All I can get is:

```
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
W/flutter: onAdFailedToLoad: 0
```

And I see this in Android Monitor:

```
E/Ads: Error waiting for future.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ae.get(:com.google.android.gms@13278037@13.2.78 (100400-210410490):11)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.g.a(:com.google.android.gms@13278037@13.2.78 (100400-210410490):13)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.c.a(:com.google.android.gms@13278037@13.2.78 (100400-210410490):65)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.c.a(:com.google.android.gms@13278037@13.2.78 (100400-210410490):198)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.f.run(:com.google.android.gms@13278037@13.2.78 (100400-210410490):1)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.m.run(Unknown Source:2)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I don't have any ad blocking installed, problem doesn't depend on type of internet connection (WiFi vs. mobile) ...

At one point I gave up. Few days later I just tried the app again and I did see some ads. But the day after that they were gone again - without any change in the app, even without a rebuild/reinstall.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v0.7.6-pre.57, on Mac OS X 10.13.5 17F77, locale cs-CZ)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.1)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2017.3.5)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
```

Comment: To be more precise - ads are not showing, that's right, but they are not LOADING, that's the problem :-)

Comment: Update: It started working again. Out of the blue. I didn't change anything in the app. I did upgrade my phone though, but It's hard to say whether it's relevant or not.

Answer (score 1):

possible reason :
internet permission in android manifest or runner info.plist file
wrong code for firebase admob
wrong placement of app id instead of ad unit id
internet service provider firewall

Answer (score 0):

Ads have to be loaded before they are shown. It can take anywhere from 3s to 10s for an ad to load after the function. The issue is that if the loadAd function is called it takes several seconds to return an ad, by which point showAd has already executed and will return an error since the ad is still loading. Report as a bug on github. loadAd functions should be added to the end of the stream in the plugin itself.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's the case, the load itself failed, even without trying to display. And I'm not trying to display ads if they are not loaded.

However - the problem solved itself by me changing nothing in my code, and I'm not sure if I updated packages. Probably yes.